# NULL tstate Error when using matplotlib together with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

I draw some matplotlib.pyplot figures onto a Tkinter GUI. When I destroy the window the "Fatal Python Error" is raised. I seem to not be the only one with the problem but I cannot read a solution to it out of the discussions. 
As it does not cause a real problem, but is just fairly inconvenient and has been bugging me for a while, I would be more than content with a way to just ignore and pass over it.

Answer (score 0):

What's your platform, python version, matplotlib version ?

-- those details matter

Try the example shown here: http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg21791.html

does it work properly?

Comment: Got a Win XP computer here, Python 2.6 and matplotlib 1.0.1.

Comment: The example code works. To close I simply destroy the root Tkinter.Tk instance. Do you think that might be it? That I need to quit() call it before? It's not that easy to test, since my program is not that simply structured, and not calling the quit in the example doesnt make that crash either.

Comment: Since you now have an example that works, I'd suggest that you try to rewrite your code along similar lines. good luck.